# How to perform binary splitting on the Chudnovsky formula?

Tags: pi

I implemented a binary splitting algorithm for calculating the digits of pi by following the algorithm on page 2 here: [binsplit.pdf](https://www.ginac.de/CLN/binsplit.pdf)

On page 4, the formula for calculating $\frac{1}{\pi}$ is given:

$$
\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{12}{C^{3/2}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(6n)!(A + nB)}{(3n)!n!^3C^{3n}}
$$

I was hoping to understand how to arrive at the binary split version below?
$$
a(n) = A + nB
$$
$$
p(n) = -(6n - 5)(2n - 1)(6n - 1)
$$
$$
q(n) = n^3\frac{C^3}{24}
$$